# Flowgear Sage Evolution How To Add User Define Fields in Document Module

Tags: jsp, flowgear

My question is how to add multiple user define/custom field into sage evolution node in flowgear.
    [I try to add user define field in Document module].

In sage evolution node there is Document module its provide
    UserDefinedFields but i am not know how to add multiple UserDefinedFields.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The UserDefinedFields element (shown in the XML schema) supports any number of child UserDefinedFieldElements. To provide multiple fields, do this:

```
<UserDefinedFields>
  <UserDefinedField>
    <Field>udffieldname1</Field>
    <Value>value1</Value>
  </UserDefinedField>
  <UserDefinedField>
    <Field>udffieldname2</Field>
    <Value>value2</Value>
  </UserDefinedField>
</UserDefinedFields>
```

Comment: I don't think QuickMap will let you do that. Take the xsl transform it generates, adapt it to your requirements and then use it on the XSL Transform Node.